# ASP.NET Repeater Selection

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a select button(`LinkButton`)  inside   the   Repeater.When  i  select the  button that  row should be appear  in  `ListView`  control.But  Repeater  control  does not   support DataKey,then how can i   achieve  this?

Comment: Its unclear to me what you try to do. Repeater did not have DataKey, but you can get your DataBase Key ID from the data and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You   can  have hidden   field  inside repeater  and achieve   your  task  as  follows:

```
protected void SelectLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    RepeaterItem item = (sender as LinkButton).Parent as RepeaterItem;
    HiddenField hdnId = item.FindControl("hdnId") as HiddenField;
    string id = hdnId.Value.ToString();// incase  your id  is  string     
    //..... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [`ItemCommand` event of `Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx). It is a kind of key.